# Sum of revision number of all xml file into json file

Tags: json, xml, xslt

I just want to read revision number of all XML file and put the addition of that revision into a new variable and then write into JSON file.

I am using XSLT for this.
I am using document function to get all required XML files.

Then I am fetching the value of all revision:

```
<SAMPLE CODE>
<XSLT>
'<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:tns="http://tnsnamespace"
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="document('C:\AW_Worksapce\File1.xml')/*"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="document('C:\AW_Worksapce\File2.xml')/*"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="document('C:\AW_Worksapce\File3.xml')/*"/>
</xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="app">
{
  <xsl:variable name="rev" select="@revision" />
    // Here some where I need to add all rev value into a
```

variable totalrev
        // Which I can use further

> e.g.  File1.xml ahhve revision = 3 File1.xml ahhve revision = 2
>   File1.xml ahhve revision = 5
>
> So output would be totalrev = 10

But I am not sure how to add them.

```
Now,

build.xml file
<fileset dir="Windows/" casesensitive="yes" id="filename.list">
        <include name="file1.xml"/>
        <include name="file2.xml"/>
        <include name="file3.xml"/>
</fileset>
<pathconvert property="filename.list.csv" refid="filename.list" pathsep="," 
/>                      

    <xslt basedir="Windows/" destdir="/meta-inf" extension=".mf" 
style="test1.xslt" >
        <mapper type="glob" from="*.xml" to="test1.mf"/>
        <param name="build_date" expression="${build.date}"/>
        <param name="dir" expression="${windows.dir}"/>
        <param name="file_list" expression="${new.filename.list.csv}"/>
    </xslt>

I want extract all three files from fileset and use like below:

XSLT File:
<xsl:variable name="docs" select="document('file1.xml') | 
document('file2.xml') | document('file3.xml')"/>

Can anyone help me here?
```

Comment: You need to show us  minimal but complete samples of XML, XSLT, output you want and output you get. If you have a single `document` call to load all files then you should be able to use e.g. `sum(document(/files/file)//sym:app_policy/@revision)` to compute the sum.

Comment: >I just want to read revision number of all xml file and put the addition of ?>that revision into new variable and then write into json file.

>I am using XSLT for this.
>I am using document function to get all required xml files.
>Then I am fetching value of all revision :

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:tns="http://tnsnamespace"
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="document('C:\AW_Worksapce\File1.xml')/*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="document('C:\AW_Worksapce\File2.xml')/*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="app">
    {
      <xsl:variable name="rev" select="@revision" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: >e.g. 
>File1.xml ahhve revision = 3
>File1.xml ahhve revision = 2
>File1.xml ahhve revision = 5

>So output would be
>totalrev = 10 


>Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Please edit your question and insert any code there as a properly formatted code snippet.

Comment: I have tried to edit my comment and format code part there, but repetitively I am getting same error that your comment contains code bla bla...

Comment: You should edit your question to insert any code there, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44900168/edit

Answer (score 0):

You could use a global variable with all documents, in XSLT 1.0 and later you can use

```
<xsl:variable name="docs" select="document('C:\AW_Worksapce\File1.xml') | document('C:\AW_Worksapce\File2.xml') | document('C:\AW_Worksapce\File3.xml')"/>
```

in XSLT 2.0 and later you can also use

```
<xsl:variable name="docs" select="document('C:\AW_Worksapce\File1.xml'), document('C:\AW_Worksapce\File2.xml'), document('C:\AW_Worksapce\File3.xml')"/>
```

in all versions you can then simply compute `sum($docs//app/@revision)`.

Comment: Getting below error on the line <xsl:variable name="docs" ...
"Expected end of the expression, found 'document'."

Comment: This error because of Multiple value in document function not allowed here?

Comment: Your stylesheet has `version="2.0"` so the suggestions should work as long as you use an XSLT 2.0 processor. If you use an XSLT 1.0 processor then use `<xsl:variable name="docs" select="document('C:\AW_Worksapce\File1.xml') | document('C:\AW_Worksapce\File2.xml') | document('C:\AW_Worksapce\File3.xml')"/>` instead.

Comment: yeh its XSLT 1.0 processor

Comment: Got it. Its working as you aid and giving me the proper addition of all revisions.
Thank you Martin. :)

Comment: Now I am facing new problem. I get the file names in a list. How to extract file names from list and put all them into the variable :
<xsl:variable name="docs" select="document(....how put file name here...)

Comment: @Akash, consider to ask a new question clearly showing how your "list" of files names looks or comes from if you can't figure it out looking at the documentation https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#document or existing examples. The document function is quite powerful so if your "list" is contained in XML elements like e.g. `<files><file>file1.xml</file><file>file2.xml</file></files>` then you can use `sum(document(files/file)//app/@revision))`.

Comment: How to get file name from fileset with xslt 1.0 in variables?
I am sending fileset from ant build.xml to xslt as param. I need to extract all file from that fileset to use further.

Comment: build.xml file
<fileset dir="Windows/" casesensitive="yes" id="filename.list">
   <include name="file1.xml"/>
   <include name="file2.xml"/>
   <include name="file3.xml"/>
</fileset>
<pathconvert property="filename.list.csv" refid="filename.list" pathsep="," />      
  
  <xslt basedir="Windows/" destdir="/meta-inf" extension=".mf" style="test1.xslt" >
   <mapper type="glob" from="*.xml" to="test1.mf"/>
   <param name="build_date" expression="${build.date}"/>
   <param name="dir" expression="${windows.dir}"/>
   <param name="file_list" expression="${new.filename.list.csv}"/></xslt>

Comment: //////////////////////
I want extract all three files from fileset and use like below:

XSLT File:
<xsl:variable name="docs" select="document('file1.xml') | document('file2.xml') | document('file3.xml')"/>

Comment: Consider to ask a new, clearly formulated and concise question with the current problem. I don't think editing a question that seemed solved with new and different requirements is the right approach here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi Martin, I have post a new question.
Link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055099/extract-all-file-name-from-fileset-in-xslt-1-0