# Extract all file name from fileset in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, ant

build.xml file

```
<fileset dir="Windows/" casesensitive="yes" id="filename.list">
    <include name="file1.xml"/>
    <include name="file2.xml"/>
    <include name="file3.xml"/>
</fileset>
<pathconvert property="filename.list.csv" refid="filename.list" pathsep="," />                      

<xslt basedir="Windows/" destdir="/meta-inf" extension=".mf" style="test1.xslt" >
    <mapper type="glob" from="*.xml" to="test1.mf"/>
    <param name="build_date" expression="${build.date}"/>
    <param name="dir" expression="${windows.dir}"/>
    <param name="file_list" expression="${new.filename.list.csv}"/>
</xslt>
```

I want extract all three files from fileset and use like below:

XSLT File:

```
<xsl:variable name="docs" select="document('file1.xml') | 
document('file2.xml') | document('file3.xml')"/>
```

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve, if the XML snippet is your input and you want to load the three referenced files then using `document(//fileset/include/@name)` is all you need to have the same as effect as `<xsl:variable name="docs" select="document('file1.xml') | 
document('file2.xml') | document('file3.xml')"/>`, except that I am not sure how to include the `dir` attribute from the parent, but the code you have posted and that I have cited does not use a directory either.

Comment: Thanks Martin.
I dont need to use hard coded file name so I am sending fileset with all those files using ant file build.xml to XSLT.
Then in XSLT I need to extract those file name from fileset and put them into document().

Comment: You might want to add an Ant tag if the question is specific to using XSLT from Ant.